# Importing Excel File to DataGridView

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

```
OpenFileDialog ofImport = new OpenFileDialog();
ofImport.Title = "Select file";
ofImport.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
ofImport.FileName = txtFileName.Text;
ofImport.Filter = "Excel Sheet(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
ofImport.FilterIndex = 1;
ofImport.RestoreDirectory = true;

if (ofImport.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{

     string path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(ofImport.FileName);
     string query = "SELECT * FROM Customer.xlsx";
     OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
     conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+ofImport.FileName+";Extended Properties=" + "\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"";
     OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);

     //DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
     adapter.Fill(dsSource);
     dataGridView1.DataSource = dsSource;

}
else
{
     ofImport.Dispose();
}
```

I want to retrive Excel data to the `DataGridView` using `dataset`. `dsSource` is the dataset used.

The Error I'm obtaing is on the line `adapter.Fill(dsSource);`:

> The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'xlsx'.
>   Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path
>   name correctly. If 'xlsx' is not a local object, check your network
>   connection or contact the server administrator.

I'm able to select the file but it is not Filling in dataset.

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Sure", "Some Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        dt = dsSource.Tables[Index];
        dt.Reset();
        Excel.Workbook workbook;
        Excel.Worksheet NwSheet;
        Excel.Range ShtRange;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelObj = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        OpenFileDialog filedlgExcel = new OpenFileDialog();
        filedlgExcel.Title = "Select file";
        filedlgExcel.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
        //filedlgExcel.FileName = textBox1.Text;
        filedlgExcel.Filter = "Excel Sheet(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
        filedlgExcel.FilterIndex = 1;
        filedlgExcel.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (filedlgExcel.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            workbook = ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open(filedlgExcel.FileName, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                 Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                 Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
            NwSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets.get_Item(1);
            ShtRange = NwSheet.UsedRange;
            for (int Cnum = 1; Cnum <= ShtRange.Columns.Count; Cnum++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn((ShtRange.Cells[1, Cnum] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString()));
            }
            dt.AcceptChanges();
            string[] columnNames = new String[dt.Columns.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                columnNames[0] = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
            }
            //string[] columnNames = (from dc in dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>() select dc.ColumnName).ToArray();


            for (int Rnum = 2; Rnum <= ShtRange.Rows.Count; Rnum++)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                for (int Cnum = 1; Cnum <= ShtRange.Columns.Count; Cnum++)
                {
                    if ((ShtRange.Cells[Rnum, Cnum] as Excel.Range).Value2 != null)
                    {
                        dr[Cnum - 1] = (ShtRange.Cells[Rnum, Cnum] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString();
                    }
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                dt.AcceptChanges();
            }
            workbook.Close(true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
            ExcelObj.Quit();

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: This is the way to fetch excel file when the name is not specified.
Write the code on the button click

Answer (score 4):

In the following line you're selecting from the *file*:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM " + ofImport.FileName;
```

You need to select from a *sheet*, however, so this should be something like this:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"; // Note the '$' sign!!
```

You need to find out the sheet name of the Excel file so you can select from it (the sheet name is displayed in the tab for the sheet - just append a `$` sign to it). The *file name*  is only used in the connection string so the database engine knows which file to open.

Think of the following analogy with usual SQL database access in .NET:

```
file name = database name
sheet name = table name
```

**EDIT**
To make things clearer: In the following picture, the sheet name is circled red. In your code,  write the sheet name in the select statement, followed by a dollar sign.

[image]

Comment: Now it is giving error
'Sheet1$' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.

Comment: When you open the Excel file in Excel, what's the name of the sheet you want to import?

Comment: The name can be according to the user so no specific name can be assigned

Comment: User will select the file according to them

Comment: Then you'll have to dynamically get the sheet names as shown in the following article (please note that this uses a different JET provider to open XLS files - keep your connection string intact!): http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8096/C-Retrieve-Excel-Workbook-Sheet-Names

Comment: For now you could just hardcode the name of a sheet for testing, so you believe me that it works as I explained :-D

Comment: It Still didnt work i hardcoded the name but same exception
The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'xlsx'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'xlsx' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.

Comment: Please update the question with the current source code you're using. The original code is now outdated, so I can't help you any further without seeing the current code.

Comment: Did you understand what I'm saying? The SQL query **can not work with the *file name* of the Excel file**!! You need to pass a **sheet name** (which is the text you see on a **tab** in the Excel file when you view it in Excel) to the query!!

Comment: Steps to make it work: First, double click the XLSX file to open it in Excel. Then, write down the text that is shown on the tab for the current sheet you're editing and close Excel again. After that, in your code, change your SQL select statement so that it ends with `FROM [<The sheet name you wrote down>$]`. Run again.

Comment: It is not showing any error but nothing is in the grid, grid is empty

Comment: This is an entirely different matter. Is there data in the sheet? Is there a headline (the "HDR" parameter in the connection string is set to `yes`, so the first line is ignored when reading the data)? Did you set the data binding for the `dataGridView1` correctly (does it bind to the right table in the data set)? Did you set a breakpoint after the `adapter.Fill`-line and inspect the contents of the data set in the debugger to see if there is any data? I suspect a data binding problem. Use `dataGridView1.DataSource = dsSource.Tables[0];` instead of `dataGridView1.DataSource = dsSource`.

Comment: I got another solution but thanks you for your effort your answer also helped me a lot

Answer (score 3):

this my code to read excel to datagridview without database configuration.

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("dataTable");
        DataSet dsSource = new DataSet("dataSet");
        dt.Reset();

        Excel.Workbook ExWorkbook;
        Excel.Worksheet ExWorksheet;
        Excel.Range ExRange;
        Excel.Application ExObj = new Excel.Application();

        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
        {
            ExWorkbook = ExObj.Workbooks.Open(openFileDialog1.FileName, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
            ExWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)ExWorkbook.Sheets.get_Item(1);
            ExRange = ExWorksheet.UsedRange;

            for (int Cnum = 1; Cnum <= ExRange.Columns.Count; Cnum++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn((ExRange.Cells[1, Cnum] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString()));
            }
            dt.AcceptChanges();

            string[] columnNames = new String[dt.Columns.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                columnNames[0] = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
            }
            //string[] columnNames = (from dc in dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>() select dc.ColumnName).ToArray();

            for (int Rnum = 2; Rnum <= ExRange.Rows.Count; Rnum++)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                for (int Cnum = 1; Cnum <= ExRange.Columns.Count; Cnum++)
                {
                    if ((ExRange.Cells[Rnum, Cnum] as Excel.Range).Value2 != null)
                    {
                        dr[Cnum - 1] = (ExRange.Cells[Rnum, Cnum] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString();
                    }
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                dt.AcceptChanges();
            }
            ExWorkbook.Close(true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
            ExObj.Quit();

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```